# How to print the the category links on a page using ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium through Python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

Using Python3 I am trying to get Chrome Webdriver and Selenium to identify the various 'Classifieds' categories on the webpage www.jtinsight.com and from there print out the category titles. So far using the code below the best i can do is get it to print out the first two - 'All categories' and 'Cars(Private)'. I have identified that the html for these two is different to the others and tried a number of different lines of code which i have listed in the code commented out, but cant identify the right tag/class/xpath etc.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Creating the WebDriver object using the ChromeDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Directing the driver to the defined url
driver.get("https://www.jtinsight.com/JTIRA/JTIRA.aspx#!/main")

# Locate the categories

# Each code line runs but only returns the first two categories
# categories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"]')
# categories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="mainCatEntry"]')
# categories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="Description"]')

# Process ran but finished with exit code 0
# categories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ng-scope"]')
# categories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ng-scope"]')
# categories = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('//href[@class="divLink"]')
# categories = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('bindonce')
# categories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="divLink"]')

# Error before finished running
# categories = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ng-scope")
# categories = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div bindonce[@class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ng-scope"]')
# categories = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('//div bindonce[@class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ng-scope"]')

# Print out all categories on current page
num_page_items = len(categories)
print(num_page_items)
for i in range(num_page_items):
    print(categories[i].text)

# Clean up (close browser once task is completed.)
driver.close()
```

Comment: `'//div[@class="mainCatEntry"]'` seems to give the results you are looking for. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: When i run it as per the code in the script it only pulls back the first two results and not all the others. What were you asking the driver to do before specifying '//div[@class="mainCatEntry"]'  ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a timing issue.  If I added a "sleep(5)" before collecting categories, it found all 24.  Interestingly, when I used a WebDriverWait instead, it would still only pull up 2 items.  So, to force the driver to do a little more work I extended the xpath.  the following worked for me:

```
categories = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="mainCatEntry"]/div[@class="Description"]')))
```

Comment: thanks for the info about the wait / sleep. As soon as i put in the delay i was able to get all the headers to come back. Now i am trying to work out how to pull out the URL's and images that go along with those headers but the dynamic html isnt making it easy.

Answer (score 0):

To identify the various *Classifieds* categories on the webpage `https://www.jtinsight.com/JTIRA/JTIRA.aspx#!/main` and print the category titles, e.g. **All categories**, **Cars (Private)**, etc, you need to *scroll* down a bit and induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.jtinsight.com/JTIRA/JTIRA.aspx#!/main")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ng-scope' and text()='Classifieds']"))));
  print([elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mainCatEntry']//div[@class='Description']")))])
  ```